# Windows 10 Icons Suddenly Grew

Tags: windows-10, icons, malware

10 minutes ago I was using google, and I kept getting requests from google saying "Unusual traffic from your computer network"

I didn't know why, but I thought what if it's malware.

I downloaded and am now scanning with Malware Bytes.

Suddenly my Icons (using Windows 10) became jumbo size.

When I check the resolution, it is  1366 x 768.

How to bring icons back to original size?

Comment: Is 1366 x 768 the recommended resolution for your display? Has anything else changed in size? If it is only your icons that became larger, you can use the scroll wheel while holding Ctrl to adjust the size of your icons.

Comment: @PFitz Yes, I believe that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Possibilities:
**Resolution**
Go into settings > system > display > advanced display settings.
From there you can change your screen resolution. Click on the selection, and make sure it is set to the one that says recommended, and press apply.
**Icon View**
Right click on your desktop and select "View", then select Medium Icons.
There's a lot more things that could be causing this, these are only 2 simple possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the icon size on the desktop you can change it by holding CTRL + scrolling the mouse wheel up or down.